# Read-only rootfs on boot

Tags: fstab, readonly, void-linux

I tried to install Void-Linux as secondary Linux on my laptop. I created a new partition for it on LVM, installed base system using [XBPS method](https://docs.voidlinux.org/installation/guides/chroot.html?search=asc) copied kernel and initramfs to my `/boot` partition and created `/etc/fstab`. It booted almost correctly but with one exception: the rootfs is readonly by default, so I need to remount it every time with `mount -o remount,rw /` after booting. I tried to add `rw` option to fstab explicetely but it didn't help:

```
# /etc/fstab
# <fs>                  <mountpoint>    <type>      <opts>                  <dump/pass>
/dev/SDD/void           /               ext4        rw,defaults,relatime    0 1
/dev/mapper/home        /home           ext4        defaults,noatime        0 0
/dev/mapper/var         /var            ext4        defaults,relatime       0 1
UUID=7720-4261          /boot           vfat        noatime,noauto          0 0
tmpfs                   /tmp            tmpfs       rw,nosuid,noatime,nodev,size=4G,mode=1777 0 0
```

```
# /boot/grub/grub.conf entry
    
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd2,gpt2'
    echo    'Loading Void Linux 5.10.8_1 ...'
    linux   /vmlinuz-5.10.8_1 root=/dev/SDD/void dolvm 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /early_ucode.cpio /initramfs-5.10.8_1.img
```

I don't have a such problem with same configuration on other Linux systems, is it related to specific behavior of Void-Linux? How to make my rootfs read-write for that case?

Comment: Did you crosspost this to https://unix.forumming.com/question/3245/read-only-rootfs-on-boot or are they scraping content from here?

Comment: @MihailMalostanidis it's my original problem, I didn't copy from anywhere, I have faced it by myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it by using `rw` kernel command line flag in grub config:

```
-     linux   /vmlinuz-5.10.8_1 root=/dev/SDD/void dolvm 
+     linux   /vmlinuz-5.10.8_1 root=/dev/SDD/void dolvm rw
```

`/etc/fstab` mount options seems to be not related to this issue.